# Scraping LinkedIn with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I am struggling a little bit with scraping LinkedIn public information. I am trying to fetch company id, or company number.

The easiest way, I thought this way, will be just open source of [page](https://www.linkedin.com/company/viiew-pty.-ltd/?originalSubdomain=sk) in any browser, and number between "3FfacetCurrentCompany%3D%255B" and "%" is the company id. Please notice that you have to be logged out of your LinkedIn account. If you are logged in, the number is invisible.

So, I was trying to open series of pages like this, for example with selenium and chromedriver, copy page_source and just use some simple regexp to retrieve this number.
Unfortunately, when I open this link with chromium and selenium, the "page_source" is completely different than I do this manually. LinkedIn is probably blocking this kind of activity, am I right?

I didn't wanted to use LinkedIn API for public information, but it seems that I need to? [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/index)

In documentation I found how to retrieve company name and other information based on company_id....but I can't find any solution how to retrieve company_id of Company based on name, page link etc...

Does anyone of you was trying to make something similar? Can I do this without login to their API?

Comment: I've just tried to open the link in Chrome, incognito mode, and I see no mention of "facetCurrentCompany" in the source of the page. All I got is a login form

Comment: In incognito mode, there is no "facet" in code, try to open link without source in Incognito mode and the LinkedIn page will try to force you to Login before. Don't open in on incognito mode and be sure that you are logged out of LinkedIn